# Python Request for Post in Secure website.

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I am still learning python and this is my first go at accessing websites and scraping certain information for myself. I am trying to get my head around the language. So any input is welcome.

The data below is what I am seeing from the page source. I have to visit a certain page to enter my login info. After successful entry. I am redirected to another page for my password. I am trying to make a post via python requests. I have to go through two pages before I can scrap the third page information. However, I am only able to get past the first page of login.

Here is the Header and POST info that is being called for the USERNAME.

For the USERNAME PAGE:

```
(Request-Line)  
POST /client/factor2UserId.recip;jsessionid=15AD9CDEB48362372EFFC268C146BBFC HTTP/1.1
Host    www.card.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
DNT 1
Referer https://www.card.com/client/
Cookie  JSESSIONID=15AD9CDEB48362372EFFC268C146BBFC
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length  13

Post Data: 
login,  USERLOGIN
```

Here is the Header and Post info that is being called for the password:

```
For the PASSWORD PAGE:
(Request-Line)  
POST /client/siteLogonClient.recip HTTP/1.1
Host    www.card.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
DNT 1
Referer https://www.card.com/client/factor2UserId.recip;jsessionid=15AD9CDEB48362372EFFC268C146BBFC
Cookie  JSESSIONID=15AD9CDEB48362372EFFC268C146BBFC
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length  133

Post Data: 
org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN,     583ed0aefe4b04b
login,  USERLOGIN
password, PASSWORD
```

This is what I have come up with however, I can only access the first page. I am being redirected back to the first page once I call my function second_pass().

With my function first_pass(), I receive a response code 200. However, I receive the same code on the second_pass(), but if I print out the text of the page, its a redirect to page one. I never successfully get to page three.

```
import requests
import re

response = None
r = None

payload = {'login' : 'USERLOGIN'}
# acesses the username screen and adds username
# give login name
def first_pass():
    global response
    global payload
    url = 'https://www.card.com/client/factor2UserId.recip'
    s = requests.Session()
    response = s.post(url, payload)
    return response.status_code


# merges payload with x that contains user password
def second_pass():
    global payload
    global r
    # global response
    x = {'password' : 'PASSWORD'} # I add the Password in this function cause I am not sure if it will fail the first_pass()
    payload.update(x)
    url = 'https://www.card.com/client/siteLogonClient.recip'
    r = requests.post(url, payload)
    return payload
    return r.status_code



# searches response for Token!
# if token found merges key:value into payload
def token_search():
    global response
    global payload
    f = response.text

    # uses regex to find the Token from the HTML
    patFinder2 = re.compile(r"name=\"(org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN)\"\s+value=\"(.+)\"",re.I)
    findPat2 = re.search(patFinder2, f)

    # if the Token in found it turns it into a dictionary. and prints the dictionary 
    # if no Token is found it prints "nothing found" 
    if(findPat2):
        newdict = dict(zip(findPat2.group(1).split(), findPat2.group(2).split()))
        payload.update(newdict)
        print payload
    else:
        print "No Token Found"
```

I call my functions right now from the shell. I call them in this order. first_pass(), token_search(), second_pass().

When I call token_search(), it updates the dictionary with unicode. I am not sure if that is what is causes my errors.

Any advice on the code would be most welcome. I enjoy learning. But at this point I am beating my head against the wall.

Comment: I have been rethinking the above, and I believe their might be a token that needs to be sent along with the post request for the password, which i defined in second_pass(). I will keep this posted, once I know what is going on.

Comment: 2 things I notice: you should be using the capitalized class `s = requests.Session()`. You're probably right about needing some other parameters. If you run through the login process in a browser with the  dev tools open (usually opens with F12) you will see the data posted for each request. Also, I don't know if requests starts a new session every time you call `requests.Session()`. That might throw off the login process.

Comment: Thank @brechin, I have been using Charles web proxy to look at the posts. They are indeed sending out a apache token along with the post. I just finished the code for the regex to obtain the token. Now, I am wondering since it captures the token in utf-8, is that going to cause me a problem while posting that code from the regex scrape. Any thoughts?? I read through the requests note and didn't see anything regarding a double call.

Comment: I updated the code above to reflect the Token issue and the capitalized class in `s = requests.Session()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting into scraping data, then I'd recommend learning about libraries like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to more robustly gather data from pages (vs. using regex).

If the token finding code works, then my recommendation would be to re-arrange the code like this. It avoids global variables, keeping variables in the scope they belong in.

```
login('USERLOGIN', 'PASSWORD')

def login(username, password):
    loginPayload = {'login' : username}
    passPayload = {'password' : password}
    s = requests.Session()

    # POST the username
    url = 'https://www.card.com/client/factor2UserId.recip'
    postData = loginPayload.copy()
    response = s.post(url, postData)
    if response.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        raise ValueError("Bad response in first pass %s" % response.status_code)
    postData.update(passPayload)
    tokenParam = token_search(response.text)
    if tokenParam is not None:
        postData.update(tokenParam)
    else:
        raise ValueError("No token value found!")
    # POST with password and the token
    url = 'https://www.card.com/client/siteLogonClient.recip'
    r = s.post(url, postData)
    return r


def token_search(resp_text):
    # uses regex to find the Token from the HTML
    patFinder2 = re.compile(r"name=\"(org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN)\"\s+value=\"(.+)\"",re.I)
    findPat2 = re.search(patFinder2, resp_text)

    # if the Token in found it turns it into a dictionary. and prints the dictionary 
    # if no Token is found it prints "nothing found" 
    if findPat2:
        newdict = dict(zip(findPat2.group(1).split(), findPat2.group(2).split()))
        return newdict
    else:
        print "No Token Found"
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections in the code. They must be something that is being requested, as I am still hitting the wall on the password page and being redirected. I will keep searching to figure it out. However the rearrangement is nice.